# How to distribute pebbles on the surface?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I've been trying to scatter pebbles across the dirt in my pot doing pretty much the same as I did by following donut tutorial by [BlenderGuru](https://www.youtube.com/c/BlenderGuruOfficial).

The thing is, that for some reason my pebbles won't appear on the surface?

[image]

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: If you're using the Geometry output of an Object Info node, you have to pick an object which defines the geometry (black box at bottom) - In other words, the Object Info Node is asking  _which_ object? You have to tell it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment by [Christopher Bennett](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/75504/christopher-bennett), when using the node `Object Info` you would also need to specify which object to use.

However, to answer your specific question even better, I would advise you to merge the objects you want to instantiate into a collection one at a time and use the node `Collection Info` instead.

Since the surface is not flat, it would make sense to adjust the rotation of the instantiated objects to these irregularities.

Furthermore, by separating the objects, you have better control over how they are distributed.

[image]

[image]